# How to update jstree node values without reload

Tags: jstree

I have a jstree that I created with the following code:

```
$('#mytree').jstree({"core": { "data" : value
                             , "themes" : { "dots": false
                                          , "icons": false }
                             }
                    }
                   );
```

I can rebuild it with new data by this code:

```
$('#mytree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = new_data;
$('#mytree').jstree(true).refresh();
```

but it can be expensive when you have a lot of nodes. What I would like to achieve is that I would like update the value of the elements (i.e. the `node.text` part) without rebuilding the whole tree. I get the new values via websocket in one message (the complete JSON string that will be the `new_data`) but the structure is not changing. How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you need is not `refresh()` but `redraw()` thus the code is

```
$('#mytree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = new_data;
$('#mytree').jstree(true).redraw(true);
```

You can find the functions in the [jstree API](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=redraw([full])).

As per zmirc suggestion, in v3.1 use:

```
$('#mytree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = new_data;
$('#mytree').jstree(true).refresh();
```

Comment: With v 3.1.0 it doesn't seem to work, unless redraw(true) is replaced with refresh().

Comment: I have been trying to use this and it seems to work but the state of the objects does not seem to be updated. Is it possible to force the newly drawn tree to conform to state options provided in the new_data?

Answer (score 2):

for deleting the node and reload tree

```
 $('#mytree').jstree(true).refresh();
```

for those who need to redraw without restart the tree use

```
jQuery('#data').jstree(true).refresh(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

worked for me:  $('#structureRows').jstree("destroy").empty();

```
function CreateStructureTree(jsonData)
        {
            $('#structureRows').jstree("destroy").empty(); 
            $('#structureRows').jstree
                ({
                    'core' : {
                        'data':
                            [

                                jsonData,
                                {
                                'id' : 'node_2',
                                'text' : 'Root node with options',
                                'state' : { 'opened' : true, 'selected' : true },
                                'children' : [ { 'text' : 'Child 1' }, 'Child 2']
                                }
                            ]

                     }
                });

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh node by this

```
$('#treeView').jstree(true).refresh_node("node_id_here")
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#mytree').jstree(true).refresh();
is working, but in my case it causes thread leak.
every refresh adds one more thread

Answer (score 0):

I load data via an url, so my refresh part looks like:

```
$('#groupTree').jstree(true).settings.core.data.url = get_group_url();
```

Answer (score -2):

1. `$('#YourJSTREE').jstree("destroy").empty();`
2. Set new data
3. `$('#YourJSTREE').jstree(true).refresh();`