# JSTree.js - making attributes retain updated values

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using JSTree.js and am trying to make attributes in LI elements in the UL list, that is using jstree, to retain updates to their values.

E.g. I have an attribute called data-cmsid that is set to a value when the tree is created.  If I change the attribute of datacmsid using some JQuery then code view shows the value has changed, but that doesn't seem to be the case in the actual js tree.

Does anybody know how to make the js tree retain attribute value changes?  I'm using drag and drop with the tree too - not sure if that affects anything?

Comment: It will be helpful if you post your code and specify the desired and error output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532967/how-to-update-jstree-node-values-without-reload ?